# Why does this not give a segmentation violation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int noOfIntegers = 2;

struct stack {
  int *s;
  int top;
} st;

void push(int item) {
  st.top++;
  st.s[top] = item;
}

int main() {
  st.s = malloc (2 * (sizeof(int)));
  st.top = -1;
  push(1);
  push(2);
  push(3);
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why this is not giving a segmentation fault, as I have malloc'd space for 2 `int`'s, and am inserting 3 into the array pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: This is the beauty of Undefined Behaviour (accessing an out-of-bounds element in your case). If you're unlucky it may work as expected; if you're lucky it will bomb out loudly.

Comment: It is more likely to corrupt the heap than create a SEGFALT.  If you tried it on a small memory implementation, like a 8051 where every byte is meticulously managed, it might do that.  But on most 32+ bit address spaces, allocation units are typically managed in 16 byte (or larger) units, so going a few bytes beyond what you asked for won't cause any trouble.

Comment: What do you believe causes a segmentation fault?  Since your belief has led you incorrectly to the conclusion that your program must produce such a fault, odds are good that your belief is incorrect. A better question therefore might be "what causes a segmentation fault?" I note this question could be answered by reading the relevant Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc` allocates space from the heap memory; you have allocated 2 `ints` on the Heap, and write 3 `ints`.

Memory for your program is typically allocated in moderately sized chunks to be more efficient for the memory manager.

Request 1 byte? You probably got 8 bytes.
Request 7 bytes? You probably got 8 bytes.
Request 14 bytes? You probably got 16 bytes.
*(or maybe its 16-bytes at a minimum...)*

You are only *guaranteed* access to the memory you actually requested, but you can sometimes write beyond that for a few bytes without causing a problem.  There's just no promise that excessive writes will be safe.  You *might* get a seg-fault, you might not!

Answer (score 14):

UPDATE: This question was the inspiration for [my ATBG column in May 2014](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/05/07/why-no-crash/). Thanks for the great question!

---

Imagine an immense minefield, stretching to the horizon. If you drive over a mine, BOOM, your car is exploded.

In the middle of that minefield are unmined parking lots, each with four thousand numbered spaces. Each parking lot has a number. Each space has a number. Some of the lots are next to each other, some are not.

You call up the parking lot manager and request eight spaces. You are told that your spaces are in lot 100, spaces 1234 through 1241.

You drive your car to the lot, find a car in space 1243, park your car in that spot, and drive away with someone else's car.

Why didn't your car explode? Because you're not in the minefield. Haven't you broken the rules? Sure. You stole someone else's parking space. Don't do that. They'll probably be mad to not find their car there. But they're not going to blow you up.

You then drive that car to spot 4003, but the lot only has 4000 spots, so you drive to spot 4000 and then drive off the right side of the parking lot to the place that would be three spots to the right of spot 4000. That turns out to be spot #3 in parking lot 101. You park your stolen car there and steal the car that was previously in that spot.

Why didn't your car explode? Because you're not in the minefield.

You then drive to spot 8003 in lot 100, which only has 4000 spots, by going all the way through lot 100, all the way through lot 101, off the right end of it, and, uh oh, this time you head into the minefield.

Why does your car explode? Because you're in the minefield.

Now is it clear why writing to memory you don't own does not guarantee a segmentation fault?  Segmentation faults mean "you are in a page of memory that *isn't even a valid page*". If you use a portion of a valid page that you're not supposed to, the operating system doens't know that.

Answer (score 1):

It will give you a segfault error or nothing if you are lucky.

You have write something in a place that can contains data use by other variable.

**EDIT:**
This doesn't produce and error because you write in memory space reserved for your programm and your OS says nothing but if you continue maybe 10 000 times you will erase data of an other program and OS will shut your program to protect other

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant. Why does a `segfault` not occur?

Comment: It doesn't occur because you are again in your reserved memory space

Comment: A segfault will occur only if you attempt to read/write to an address that is not mapped to the virtual memory space of your process. Keep pushing items and you will reach an address that triggers the segfault.

Comment: @user43968 Actually, OS allocates blocks from VM for the process. This process can't erase data of another one. Thus this sentence: "if you continue maybe 10 000 times you will erase data of an other program and OS will shut your program to protect other" is incorrect.

Comment: @chrk: not in general. There are still applications that don't have virtual memory and microcontrollers that do not even have an MMU.

Comment: @mfro True, I assumed that OP's process isn't on one of these though. But you're right in general. +1