# Heartbleed: Payloads and padding

Tags: security, ssl, heartbleed-bug

I am left with a few questions after reading the RFC 6520 for Heartbeat:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6520

Specifically, I don't understand why a heartbeat needs to include arbitrary payloads or even padding for that matter. From what I can understand, the purpose of the heartbeat is to verify that the other party is still paying attention at the other end of the line.

What does these variable length custom payloads provide that a fixed request and response do not?

E.g.

```
Alice: still alive?
Bob: still alive!
```

After all, FTP uses the NOOP command to keep connections alive, which seem to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, in fact, a reason for this payload/padding within [RFC 6520](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6520)

From the document:

> The user can use the new HeartbeatRequest message,
> which has to be answered by the peer with a HeartbeartResponse
> immediately.  To perform PMTU discovery, HeartbeatRequest messages
> containing padding can be used as probe packets, as described in
> [[RFC4821]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4821).

---

>In particular, after a number of retransmissions without
   receiving a corresponding HeartbeatResponse message having the
   expected payload, the DTLS connection SHOULD be terminated.

---

>When a HeartbeatRequest message is received and sending a
   HeartbeatResponse is not prohibited as described elsewhere in this
   document, the receiver MUST send a corresponding HeartbeatResponse
   message carrying an exact copy of the payload of the received
   HeartbeatRequest.

> If a received HeartbeatResponse message does not contain the expected
> payload, the message MUST be discarded silently.  If it does contain
> the expected payload, the retransmission timer MUST be stopped.

Credit to [pwg](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7558619) at HackerNews. There is a good and relevant discussion there as well.

Comment: So basically heartbeat is tailored for DTLS and then important people decided that it could be used for TLS as well, despite being overly complex for the purpose.

Also, the comment about misbehaving servers is preposterous. If you don't even trust you peers to respond honestly to your echo requests, why would you trust them at all?

Answer (score 1):

(The following is not a direct answer, but is here to highlight related comments on another question about Heartbleed.)

---

There are arguments against the protocol design that allowed an arbitrary limit - either that there should have been no payload (or even echo/heartbeat feature) or that a small finite/fixed payload would have been a better design.

From the comments on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23090802/2864740) in [Is the heartbleed bug a manifestation of the classic buffer overflow exploit in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089964/is-the-heartbleed-bug-a-manifestation-of-the-classic-buffer-overflow-exploit-in)

> (R..) In regards to the last question, I would say any large echo request is malicious. It's consuming server resources (bandwidth, which costs money) to do something completely useless. There's really *no valid reason for the heartbeat operation to support any length but zero*
>
> (Eric Lippert) Had the designers of the API believed that then they would not have allowed a buffer to be passed at all, so clearly they did not believe that. *There must be some by-design reason to support the echo feature; why it was not a fixed-size 4 byte buffer, which seems adequate to me, I do not know.*
>
> (R..) .. Nobody thinking from a security standpoint would think that supporting arbitrary echo requests is reasonable. Even if it weren't for the heartbleed overflow issue, there may be cryptographic weaknesses related to having such control over the content the peer sends; this seems unlikely, but *in the absence of a strong reason to support a[n echo] feature, a cryptographic system should not support it*. It should be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the exact motivation behind this decision, it may have been motivated by the ICMP echo request packets used by the [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) utility. In an ICMP echo request, an arbitrary payload of data can be attached to the packet, and the destination server will return exactly that payload if it is reachable and responding to ping requests. This can be used to verify that data is being properly sent across the network and that payloads aren't being corrupted in transit.

Comment: But ICMP echo request works at the IP level of the network stack. TLS runs on top of TCP which runs on top of IP. TCP already makes guarantees about data integrity, so there is no reason why TLS should be concerned.